# Time Request in web.config for API .Net 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, httpclient

The API receives a request, but it takes too long to save data from the API to the database. After 100 seconds, there is a timeout problem on client side. Can I edit this time on the API side? not on client side so not HttpClient.

I added web.config file manually in my project and wrote this code but it does not increase timeout.

Web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
   </handlers>
   <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" hostingModel="InProcess" />
 </system.webServer>


<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" maxRequestLength="4096" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
       minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Is your project hosted in IIS?

Comment: I dont think that you can configure the clients timeout on the server side. The default HttpClient Timeout is 100 seconds, that is why the client aborts here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-7.0

Comment: @GuruStron I have tried every combination (IISExpress,http,https)

Answer (score 0):

###### After 100 seconds, there is a timeout problem on client side.

Yes, because default timeout for `HttpClient is 100 seconds. From [`HttpClient.Timeout`][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-7.0) docs:

> The default value is 100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds).

You can't edit client settings on the server side (in general case you are not guaranteed that `HttpClient` will be used by client), so this should be set up client side.

Also I would argue that long running endpoints should be refactored in some  kind of asynchronous model (websockets or just splitting in 2 two endpoints - one posts the request and the other provides the status).